# In Azure DevOps Server 2022 my build pipeline is creating DLLs with a timestamp different from UTC or local time

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

I've just started with Pipelines and have Build and Release working for a simple .NET Core web app.

The Azure DevOps Server host is Windows Server 2019 and Time Zone is set to Eastern Standard Time.

However, the built DLLs are timestamped 10 hours into the future, which feels like something is using UTC+0500 when it should be using UTC-0500.

I could find no time zone settings at the Azure DevOps Server, Collection, Project, or Pipeline levels. (Most of the product documentation drives one to Azure DevOps **Service** settings, which don't apply here.)

The documentation says ADO Pipelines operate in UTC and looking at my build task's log I am seeing UTC timestamps. So I *might* expect artifacts to have timestamps 5 hours into the future. But when I look at the resulting files in the file system, I see them as modified 10 hours in the future.

Is this expected behavior? Is there something I can adjust to make this more rational?

Comment: The dll is built on your agent machine. Could you please check what's the time zone on the agent machine?

Comment: Hi again, @wadezhou-MSFT! Thanks for your quick response. 

The agent is running on the Azure DevOps host, so also EST.

Comment: What if you directly build the project on local self-hosted machine? Is the time zone correct? Should be same with local machine.

Comment: All the action is taking place on the same host. When I build in VS2022 I get the proper timestamp (current in my timezone). When I build through DevOps I get 10 hours into the future. Are you suggesting a third approach by "directly build the project," different from building in VS?

Comment: No, asking to build on local machine is a `debug` step, to check if the project itself has some setting. As per your result, the timestamp should be caused by some other settings.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I've looked for but not found any setting that explains the 10-hour delta. I could see a 5-hour delta: host in EST; ADO building in UTC and writing out the "wrong" version of the timestamp. But 5?

Comment: I suppose when we go from EST to EDT we'll see if the delta changes from 10 to 8. ;-)

Comment: Yes, please give a check. In addition, what the time output if you add `- powershell: get-date` in the pipeline? Is it also 10 hours lag?

Comment: I see localtime in the PowerShell task inside a build pipeline:
`2024-02-07T14:21:37.9143553Z get-date returns 02/07/2024 09:21:37`

Comment: Checked on my ADO server 2022 env, the dll creation time is based on the agent time.  may i know if you build the dll in the docker? You can share the pipeline definition in the statement so that it's more clear. And did you check the dll timestamp on the agent machine directly? If you copy it to other machine, the timestamp could change.

Comment: I add the more details in the reply, please check, let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Hi @RichardWells, may i know if there's any update? Please check my detail reply below, the dll creation time is only depending on the time on agent machine. Make sure you checked on the agent machine for the dll creation time.

Comment: Hi @wadezhou-MSFT: thanks for your additional feedback and apologies for not responding more immediately. I've put this work on the back-burner for the moment and will review your detailed input again when I return to it. You should consider this concern to be addressed unless I return with any follow-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Checked on my ADO server 2022 env, the dll creation time is based on the agent time.

My yaml:

```
pool:
  name: selfpool1

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- powershell: |
   get-date
   Get-TimeZone
   Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp10.dll  -Force | Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, Mode, Length
```

Scenario1:
`UTC-6 time zone` setting on agent machine, the dll creation time is below:
[image]

Scenario2:
Change the time zone to `UTC-5` on agent machine, the dll creation time changed to 1hour later.

[image]

The creation time changed is due to the agent time zone change.  In addition, if i copy the dll to another environment, the timestamp will be changed.

[image]

You can follow the sample powershell script to get the dll creation time for a check. in addition, don't move the dll to another environment as it could change the time zone on the timestamp.